# How to add custom column in CGridView in YII?

Tags: yii

I need to add a column in CGridView.

I use this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'user-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
            'filter'=>$model,
            'pager' => array(
                'firstPageLabel' => '&lt;&lt;', 
                ),
            'columns'=>array(
                'username',
                'name',
                'email',
                'creationDate',
                array(
                        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                        'template' => '{change} {view}',
                        'buttons' => array(
                                        'change' => array(
                                                    'url'=> "'http://test.com/userservice/".$model->username."'",
                                        ),
                        ),

                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'test',
                    'value' => 'testtest', 
                )
            ),
));
```

But I got error:

> Property "User.test" is not defined.

Comment: Look [using-standard-filters-in-cgridview-custom-fields](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/117/using-standard-filters-in-cgridview-custom-fields/), for more informations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're almost there, in your column array you would use the `name` param for attributes of the  model in the dataprovider, instead for custom columns you can use `header` like so:

```
'columns'=>array(
    ...
    array(
        'header' => 'test',
        'value' => '"testtest"', 
    ),
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write normal code on CGridView like this .

```
'columns'=>array(
                'username',
                'name',
                'email',
                'creationDate',
                'test',
                  ---
            ),
```

If you put code like this on your respective model .

```
    ---
    public $test ; 
    public function afterFind() {
        $this->test = 'Test Variable' ; // put your custom code to reflect exact need 
        return parent::afterFind();
    }
    ---
```